# How to conditionally do a vlookup in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to do a vlookup to pick out the latest price to fill up a second table. An example below. For item #1, the latest price is at Month `6 (=$6)` while item #2 is at Month `5 (=$4)`. What's the best way to fill up Table B? Note: There might be occasion that `item_id` cannot be found in Table A if the item is new.

Any guidance? Many Thanks.

Table A (Reference)

```
| Item_ID | Month | Price |
|---------|-------|-------|
| 1       | 4     | 10    |
| 1       | 5     | 8     |
| 1       | 6     | 6     |
| 2       | 5     | 4     |
```

Table B (To Fill)

```
| Shop_ID | Item_ID | Price |
|---------|---------|-------|
| 1       | 1       | 6     |
| 1       | 2       | 4     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find the latest information, then merge it to create the table:

```
import pandas


tableA = pandas.DataFrame({'Item_ID': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2},
                           'Month': {0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 5},
                           'Price': {0: 10, 1: 8, 2: 6, 3: 4}})
tableB = pandas.DataFrame({'Item_ID': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 
                           'Price': {0: 6, 1: 4}, 
                           'Shop_ID': {0: 1, 1: 1}})

latest = tableA.loc[tableA.groupby('Item_ID')['Month'].idxmax()]
result = tableB[['Shop_ID', 'Item_ID']].merge(latest[['Item_ID', 'Price']],
                                              on='Item_ID')
```

This yields

```
       Shop_ID  Item_ID  Price
0        1        1      6
1        1        2      4
```

Answer (score 2):

To fill column `Price` in `df2` we can create a Pandas series with Item_ID and Price. Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for last row for each `Item_ID` and create `Series` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and selecting column. Lastly create new column with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html).

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data1 = dict(Item_ID=[1,1,1,2], Month=[4,5,6,5], Price = [10,8,6,4])
data2 = dict(Shop_ID=[1,1],Item_ID=[1,2])

# Create dfs
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Crete a series with Item_ID as index and Price as value
s = df1.drop_duplicates('Item_ID', keep='last').set_index('Item_ID')['Price']

# Create new column in df2
df2['Price'] = df2['Item_ID'].map(s)
print (df2)
```

Returns:

```
   Shop_ID  Item_ID  Price 
0        1        1      6 
1        1        2      4
```

---

**Further Details**

If necessary use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) first

```
s = (df1.sort_values(['Item_ID','Month'])
        .drop_duplicates('Item_ID', keep='last')
        .set_index('Item_ID')['Price'])
```

the serie `s` looks like this:

```
Item_ID
1    6
2    4
Name: Price, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This answer was nice, took the liberty do add some data and throw things around +1

Comment: @AntonvBR - Thank you very much.